# Can't find Cakephp 2 shell in webhost cron

Tags: shell, cakephp, cron

I wrote a Cakephp Weather shell and can run it in my localhost via a windows task. So far so good :)
Now I want to run the same shell as a cron in my webhosting. I've read [the Cakephp docs](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html) but unfortunately my host only support inserting a url to the script:

[image]

So they told me to send me the script and the are willing to insert it on server level. I think I already send them 10 times another script and it never works (kind of trial and error). The say the log file shows the following error:

---

```
Nov 22 15:05:01 com-linssh022.srv.combell-ops.net CRON daemon: Executing (31531)
'cd /staging.bellewaerdefun.be/app && Console/cake Weather'
Nov 22 15:05:01 com-linssh022.srv.combell-ops.net CRON daemon: /bin/bash: line
0: cd: /staging.bellewaerdefun.be/app: No such file or directory
Nov 22 15:05:01 com-linssh022.srv.combell-ops.net CRON daemon: 1 processes
running
Nov 22 15:05:01 com-linssh022.srv.combell-ops.net CRON daemon: Executed (31531)
'cd /staging.bellewaerdefun.be/app && Console/cake Weather'
```

---

I already send them the following scripts:

- */5  *    *    *    *  cd /staging.bellewaerdefun.be/app &&
  Console/cake Weather
- */5  *    *    *    *  cd
  /data/sites/web/bellewaerdefunbe/subsites/staging.bellewaerdefun.be/app &&
  Console/cake Weather
- */5  *    *    *    *  cd /staging.bellewaerdefun.be/app &&
  Console/cake Weather
- */5 * * * * /data/sites/web/bellewaerdefunbe/subsites/staging.bellewaerdefun.be/app &&
  Console/cake Weather
- */5 * * * * cd
  /data/sites/web/bellewaerdefunbe/subsites/staging.bellewaerdefun.be/app &&
  Console/cake Weather
- ...

As you can see, it's trial and error but nothing works. I realy don't understand why this isn't working. The script seems to be OK, isn't it? Anyone who see the mistake in it?

---

### EDIT on 24/12/17

I’ve been looking around and tried some other things. It’s very time-consuming that I’m not able to test it myself and I should wait until my hosting provider changes the cronjob on server level. In fact: my best option looked this one:

*/5 * * * * /data/sites/web/bellewaerdefunbe/subsites/staging.bellewaerdefun.be/app && Console/cake Weather

But the database isn’t changing after 5 server minutes. Perhaps I’m missing something? Is there anyone in for a non-material christmas present please :)